# No data in beautifulsoup result (python). Why?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Hello, I`m python begginer, so have problem with windugru site data parsing.
The result I got below: no data between span tag.

**"span class="wgs_wind_avg_value"></span"**

Who can support please in scope of this problem?

code you can read below again:
thanks in advance!

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

try:
WIND = 'https://www.windguru.cz/station/3303'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'}


full_page = requests.get(WIND, headers=headers)
soup_eur = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')

wind_speed = soup_eur.findAll("span", {"class": "wgs_wind_avg_value"})


print(wind_speed)

except:
print("smth wrong")
```

Comment: The value(s) you're looking for are dynamic (Javascript). You should use something like *selenium* for this

Comment: site have API you dont need to use selenium

Comment: Sergey,
Could you please share info how to use API with this web site?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the API, here's an example using *selenium* (Chrome)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get('https://www.windguru.cz/station/3303')
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wgs_wind_avg_value')))
    print(element.text)
```

**Output:**

```
10.3
```